# Get Field Value from Quotation and Cast to Its Type

Tags: f#, quotations

I would like to get the typed value for a field from a record in a `Quotation`. It seems like it should be straight forward but I'm a bit lost.

E.g.,

```
type FullName = { First : string; Last : string }

type Name = { Name : FullName }

let t = { Name = { First = "Jon"; Last = "N" } }

let name = <@ t.Name.First @>
```

Then I would like to take the value `name` and get the `Jon` as a `string` (not an `obj`). How would I do this? Sometimes the return value might be an `Array` or another `Record`.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I'll be using this function at the edges of F# so it needs to check for `null`:

```
let getValue (expr: Quotations.Expr<'t>) =
    match eval expr with
    | null -> None
    | x -> Some ((eval expr) :?> 't)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to compile and execute the quotation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: How do I extract the actual value from the quotation with its type? Sorry, I'm not sure how to make it more clear.

Comment: Right now I'm just playing with it in the scripts. I found this snippet that gets me halfway there but it returns it at an `obj` http://www.fssnip.net/h1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [eval script](http://www.fssnip.net/h1) that you linked will get you half way there - it will compute the actual value of the expression for you. Now all that's left to do is to cast that value to the appropriate type:

```
let getValue (expr: Quotations.Expr<'t>) = (eval expr) :?> 't

let valueOfName = getValue name  // valueOfName : string
```

Keep in mind that *theoretically* the cast may crash, but in practice that shouldn't happen, because `eval` would always return a value of the right type (unless there is a bug in it).